# javascript loop through multiple conditions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a loop that executes the code and observes the cellphone alpha and then go to a specific page, but my loop it's only working with my first and second case if, and first else if.

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation",findPlace);

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    findPlace();
}

function findPlace(evt) {

       if (evt.alpha < 90 || evt.alpha > 360) {
            unit.goToScreenAction(ctx, { screen: unit.find('Norte') }, noop);
            window.alpha = evt.alpha;
unit.find('alphatxt').setText(window.alpha + '');
        } 
        else if (evt.alpha < 180 || evt.alpha > 90) {
            unit.goToScreenAction(ctx, { screen: unit.find('Este') }, noop);
            window.alpha = evt.alpha;
unit.find('alphatxt3').setText(window.alpha + '');
        }
        else if (evt.alpha < 360 || evt.alpha > 270) {
            unit.goToScreenAction(ctx, { screen: unit.find('Sur') }, noop);
            window.alpha = evt.alpha;
unit.find('alphatxt1').setText(window.alpha + '');
        } 

        else if (evt.alpha < 270 || evt.alpha > 180) {
            unit.goToScreenAction(ctx, { screen: unit.find('Oeste') }, noop);
                        window.alpha = evt.alpha;
unit.find('alphatxt2').setText(window.alpha + '');
        }  
        else {
            unit.goToScreenAction(ctx, { screen: unit.find('Nada') }, noop);
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify more on what you want each particular if/else-if statement to test for? I have a feeling that some of your `||` are meant to be `&&`.

Comment: `findPlace()` requires an `evt` argument, but you're not passing any argument to it in the loop.

Comment: @J.Chen I'm pretty sure *all* of them should be `&&`.

Comment: You're using `>` and `<` in all your tests. So if the value is exactly `==` to any of those values, none of the conditions will match. Did you really want to go to `Nada` when `alpha` is `90`, `180`, `270`, or `360`?

Comment: Hi there each if  else if stament is going to test the alpha in the deviceorientation, for exameple if the degrees are 88 it should be going to Norte, and so on, but in my test it only works with Norte and then it evaluates and goes to south and nothing else... And "nada" only happens when theres no degrees in there.

heres an example of my development http://celtra.adsmovil.com/preview/6e24f0bd#deviceType=Phone

Comment: I edited the code and added && and <= and >= but now the frist if is not working for some reason, and i had to change the Norte to my last else

Comment: btw THX TO U ALL!!!!! all ur replies worked for me :)

Answer (score -1):

You’re mingling synchronous and asynchronous code.

When you’re attaching a `deviceorientation` event handler, it’s synchronous. The `for` loop is executed synchronously right after.

When a `deviceorientation` event is fired, your `findPlace` function is called asynchronously. In other words, your script doesn’t make the call. The browser does.

The thing is, you’re also calling `findPlace` synchronously within you `for` loop. And your `count` variable is not defined.

You might be confused because of the term “event loop” sometimes used in event-based frameworks in other languages such as Java or C++. With JavaScript, the event loop is handled by the browser. You don’t have to care about it. Just register event handlers and your code is rollin’.

Now pay attention to other comments, you have logical issues inside the `findPlace` function that need to be addressed.

---

**Edit:** to make a more complete answer, here’s how your `if/else` structure should look like:

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation",findPlace);

function findPlace(evt) {
  if (evt.alpha >= 0 && evt.alpha < 90) {
    ...
  }
  else if (evt.alpha >= 90 && evt.alpha < 180) {
    ...
  }
  else if (evt.alpha >= 180 && evt.alpha < 270) {
    ...
  }
  else if (evt.alpha >= 270 && evt.alpha < 360) {
    ...
  }
  else {
    unit.goToScreenAction(ctx, { screen: unit.find('Nada') }, noop);
  }
}
```

Not sure about the case of `alpha` being *exactly* 360. Spec says it may happen, but it’s equivalent to 0. Anyway, that’s a rare enough case and doesn’t cause much trouble.

Comment: Now im trying to figure out why android have a different alpha on start :/

Comment: As stated [on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation): “Warning: Chrome and Firefox do not handle the angles the same way, so on some axes the direction are reversed.” Guess you can substitute “Chrome” with “Android”. Were you testing with Firefox in the first place?